# Is rebasing a tag in Mercurial allowed?

Tags: mercurial, rebase

To update the version number in our software, a script does the following:

```
$ hg update v3.3
(sed+awk magic to edit version numbers in code base)
$ hg commit -m"Create v3.3.50"
$ hg tag v3.3.50
$ hg push    
abort: push creates new remote head 101b0ff402c6 on branch 'v3.3'!
(pull and merge or see "hg help push" for details about pushing new heads)
$ hg pull --branch v3.3 --rebase
...
adding file changes
added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files (+1 heads)
$ hg push
...
added 2 changesets with 4 changes to 4 files
```

But after the commit, the tag doesn't seem to exist in the destination repository:

```
$ hg tags | grep v3.3.50
$
```

Confusingly, the tag is in the .hgtags file:

```
$ grep v3.3.50 .hgtags 
e7d6c19f8dd86cdad4cb41f543d09dbe5d30405e v3.3.50
```

And is in the revision history:

```
$ hg log -b v3.3
changeset:   7067:701358ca0f4b
branch:      v3.3
user:        Joe User <juser@example.com>
date:        Wed Nov 11 12:41:15 2015 -0800
summary:     Added tag v3.3.50 for changeset e7d6c19f8dd8

changeset:   7066:19aafdd33263
branch:      v3.3
user:        Joe User <juser@example.com>
date:        Wed Nov 11 12:41:15 2015 -0800
summary:     Create v3.3.50
```

The `hg commit / tag / push` sequence works as expected, but adding the rebase seems to, at least partially, remove the tag. Do tags require some special handling with regard to the rebase command?

Mercurial version is 2.9.2 and system in question is running a recent version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is either an oversight or intentional design, and it's difficult to tell which it is (more on that below).

You can fix it by updating to the head of the branch and retagging via:

```
hg tag -f -r REVID TAGNAME
```

Being able to change or delete tags is [intended design](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TagDesign#Mutable), so this is not anything outlandish. The original tag commit will stay around, though.

If you want to be explicit about this being a tag update, use

```
hg tag -f -e -r REVID TAGNAME
```

which allows you to edit the tag commit message to say that it's an update of the original tag.

If you have evolve installed, you can avoid looking up the original revision and use:

```
hg tag --hidden -f -r 'successors(TAGNAME)' TAGNAME
```

Here, the `successors(...)` revset function describes which revision the original revision tagged with `TAGNAME` has morphed into.

If you have evolve or use `hg histedit` (and your rebased history doesn't contain merges since the tag), you can also (in principle) change the original tag commit, though I'd advise against it, as it can be a bit finicky (you basically have to edit `.hgtags` manually and update the commit message).

If you wish to do this, the easiest way to do this with evolve is:

```
hg update --hidden -r 'successors(TAGNAME)'
edit .hgtags                                 # update tag information
hg commit --amend                            # update commit message
hg evolve -a                                 # propagate changes
```

This is a bit more complicated with histedit:

```
hg histedit -r REVID                         # REVID = tag commit
# In the histedit editor, change "pick" to "edit" for the tag commit,
# then write the file and leave the editor.
edit .hgtags                                 # update tag information
hg commit                                    # provide new commit message
hg histedit --continue                       # rebuild rest of history
```

Both approaches rely on the fact that `hg tag` simply does a normal commit that alters `.hgtags` and auto-generates a commit message. Mercurial will only rely on the information in `.hgtags` and not check any metadata. I'd also recommend making a local clone of the repository beforehand, just in case you make a mistake and don't know how to recover from it.

Again, I don't think this is necessary (or even a good idea), but the decision is ultimately yours.

---

So, is this a bug or by design? One problem with moving the tag automatically during a rebase would be that the original revision often stays around (`hg rebase --keep` or just plain rebase with evolve), and in this case it isn't clear whether you want to move the tag or not. It also doesn't solve the similar problem with `hg graft`. So, it could be either.

Answer (score 2):

Tags in the `.hgtags` file are identified by the changeset hash id. Rebasing a changeset changes the hash since data about its parent is included when computing the hash.

In your example output, the "Create v3.3.50" changeset has a hash of "19aafdd33263" - and that is different from the `e7d6c19f8dd8` referenced in the tags file and the tag changeset.

Do note, though, that you can rebase the changeset that added the tag since the tagged changeset hash will not change.

Answer (score 0):

We also came across this problem recently and tried to provide complex solutions for it including history manipulation and updating commit messages and so on. At the end we realized, that it is wrong to rebase an unpushed changeset, because we are then moving something that is pointing to a unique snapshot of out repository to a new snapshot, which is not the same, due to what is done by rebase, so we ended up with following rule and changed our scripts accordingly:

> Never tag an unpushed changeset

I.e. in our build script we now `pull`, test, increment versions, `commit`, `pull --rebase` if required, **`push`** and remember hash, then `tag` on **that** hash, `commit`, `pull --rebase` again if needed (now nothing can be damaged any more), and finally `push` the change done to ".hgtags".

I opened a feature request for Mercurial to address this in a better way:
https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5352